# Why do I need to reboot after adding a user to the Topology Manager Administrators group?

Tags: web8, topology-manager

After installing Topology Manager on a CM server with another Admin account my account is not authorised to run the TTM Powershell Commandlets. I get

> Authorization has been denied for this request.

My account is a member of the local Administrator group which is named in the Topology Manager Administrators group and this group is referenced correctly in `SDLWeb\Topology Manager\web\web.config`.

I have rebooted the server.
The only way that I can get my account to run the commandlets is to add my account name to the Topology Manager Administrators group AND reboot the server.

1. Does Powershell not dynamically reflect the state of local group permissions?
2. Is there a way I can update this information after a group member change without rebooting?

Comment: Isn't `IISRESET` sufficient?

Comment: I've not seen any change after running IISRESET. Only after a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Please ignore the question. The test user concerned was not logging out and back in after the group changes. He assumed that such things were dynamic, but they are not. Powershell might behave a bit like Linux sometimes but not when it comes to authentication tokens.

The observation on membership of the Administrators group still holds true.